# Two URLClassLoaders with the same classpath with different behaviour

Tags: java, scala, gradle, groovy

I am in a situation where this gives an exception

```
this.class.classLoader.loadClass("X") // fine
this.class.classLoader.loadClass("X").getMethods() // ClassNotFoundException for Y
```

But the following is OK

```
def MyClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(this.class.classLoader.getURLS())
MyClassLoader.loadClass("X").getMethods() // fine
```

What can explain this? This is all coming when running a gradle plugin, the classes classloader is a VisitableURLClassLoader coming from gradle and is in a chain of 7 classloaders. I don't have multiple copies of X or Y on my classpath.

All I can imagine is that say the chain of classloaders is C1 > C2 > C3 > C4 > C5 > C6 > C7, where C7 is my classes classloader. Then it is able to loadClass via C3 say, but Y is found in C4, and since the class was loaded with C3, it doesn't look in C4 and so doesn't find Y. This makes sense (to me), but I don't know how I would debug this.

Answer (score 1):

It was the one thing I imagined. I should have tested. The classloader C lives in a chain of classloaders, X could be found in the parent classloader P, while Y could only be found in C. Since X was loaded via P, it looked for Y in P, didn't find it, hence the exception.